# Why does postgres distinct assign a type to strings?

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, distinct

If you execute `SELECT 'test', 123` the output will be two columns, the first with an unknown data type and the second with a data type of integer.

If you execute `SELECT DISTINCT 'test', 123` the output will be two columns, the first with a data type of text and the second with a data type of integer.

Why does adding `DISTINCT` function different from running the query without `DISTINCT` in regards to the data type?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This behaviour is described in [Chapter 10. Type Conversion](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/typeconv.html).

In [10.1. Overview](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/typeconv-overview.html) you can find:

> If a type is not specified for a string literal, then the placeholder type unknown is assigned initially, to be resolved in later stages.

To select distinct values Postgres has to convert string literals to a type with equality operator. The case is analogous to union:

```
select 'abc', 1
union
select 'def', 1
```

where the first column is resolved as `text`. The rule is described in [10.5. UNION, CASE, and Related Constructs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/typeconv-union-case.html):

> 3. If all inputs are of type unknown, resolve as type text (the preferred type of the string category).